# NSUnderlineStyleSingle is two pixels

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I am trying to get a line below the attributed string on my custom NSView (NSButton attributedString) and I am using the NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName

```
    [self addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) range:range];
```

And the result on the non-retina screen is like:
[image: Underline is too thick]

This line is very thick (2 pixels), I tried all various combinations of NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, plus tried to offset the Y axis by 0.25f or 0.50f but this doesn't solve the problem, it makes it just blurry as "expected"

So any ideas? I don't want to draw the line my self in code, I am looking for a solution with attributed strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with the typeface being used, as others with the NSUnderlineStyleSingle attribute don't exhibit the same behavior.

Ex:

- [Avenir Next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnPox.png)
- [Lato (the font in use)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrwHI.png)